# How to parse a string with no delimiter?

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have a frame that I want to parse. It is a String, and the fields have no delimiters, and have different lengths. How can I get those fields (using Java)?

For example the frame: $XXYYYU#

How can I get the content of the fields 'XX', 'YYY' and 'U' ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we have an example string because the answer is most likely going to be based off of its contents.

Comment: If you don't have delimiters you should at least know the exact length of every single part you want to extract, i don't think it's possible, you would have to "guess" what is the right part to extract

Comment: The string is like the frame in the example. It is in a .txt file, and I want to parse it to get some fields.

Comment: Is XX *always* two characters, and YYY *always* three characters and U *always* one character? If so, just use substring.

Comment: @BackSlash, the length of the fields is different. That's my problem. i don't know if it is possible.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I hope so. I have to confirm that. But I'm assuming that the length is always the same. Thanks, I will see how substring works.

Comment: Confirm? How can you ask a question on SO without knowing your requirements?

Comment: @AdamSiemion, for now, the response of Mena, below, is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the lengths will be consistent, you can try the `substring` method of `String`.

For instance:

```
package test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myString = "$XXYYYU#";
        String xx = myString.substring(1, 3);
        String yyy = myString.substring(3, 6);
        String u = myString.substring(6, 7);
        System.out.println(xx + " " + yyy + " " + u);

    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
XX YYY U
```

Comment: Read the question: **the fields have no delimiters, and have different lengths**

Comment: @BackSlash, the fields have different lengths from each other. But I'm assuming that each field will always have the same length in every frames. If so, this will works.

Comment: Ok, if they don't have the same length after all, but fall into some recognizable pattern (for instance adjacent equal characters or character types, etc.) you might want to try regular expressions as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problem will be best to iterate string and parse it manually.

```
char lastChar = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < str.Length - 1; i++)
{
   if (lastChar != str[i])
   {
     System.out.println();
     lastChar = str[i];
   }

   System.out.print(str[i]);  
}
```

This should produce:

```
XX
YYY
UU
```